# Call hprose.httpclient asynchronously in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, angular-promise

I have a Hprose server which handles user authentication. I am trying to write a logonService which returns a UserInfo object after user logged in. In the code below, hprose.HttpClient.login() is called asynchronously and it takes seconds, but the code in controller keeps going after creating the logonService instance. so that $scope.user is always null, and logonService.logon() is never called. I tried to use $http.get, but cannot figure out how to get a Promise obj using Hprose, instead of Http as in the sample code. A search in Google does not come up with anything useful. Anyone has idea what to do? Thanks.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[])
  .service("logonService", function() {
     var httpclient = new hprose.HttpClient("http://testurl.com:4800/webapi/", ["login"]);
     httpclient.login("userid", "ppt", function(sid) {
        console.log("sid1="+sid);
     }
     this.logon = function() {
        console.log("here I am");
        return something;
     }
    })
   .controller（"myCtrl", ["logonService", function(logonService) {
       var user = logonService.logon();
       $scope.user = user;
   }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of problem is the code in `myCtrl` does not wait for asychronous result of `logonService.logon()`.  Also, we don't know if `httpclient.login()` returns promises or what.  So we need to wrap that in $q promise.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[])

app.service("logonService", function() {
    var loginURL = "http://testurl.com:4800/webapi/";
    var httpclient = new hprose.HttpClient(loginUrl, ["login"]);

    // wrap login fn w/ new $q promise
    this.logon = function(userid, ppt) {
        return $q(function(resolve,reject){ 
            httpclient.login(userid, ppt, function(sid) {
                console.log("sid1="+sid);
                // resolve or reject fn based on results passed to callback
                if (sid) {
                resolve(sid);
                } else {
                reject('sid wasn\'t defined!');
                }
            })
        }
    }

})

app.controller（"myCtrl", ["logonService", 
    function(logonService) {
        logonService.logon(userid, ppt).then(function(user){
            //  assign user to scope only after promise resolved
            //  'user' arg will be whatever passed to 'resolve' above
            $scope.user = user; 
        })
        .catch(function(e){
            console.log('An Error happened: ' + e)
            // logon server was down, etc.
        })
    }
])
```

[**Here**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) is the good reference for AngularJS' `$q`.  That will let you know how to create Promise in any situation.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Are you sure you mean `logonService.logon()`? As written, it's a promise not a method.

Comment: Better, but bracket/braces need sorting.

Comment: Last four lines of the service are still wrong. There's a missing ')' and all four should really have semi-colons.

Comment: In any case, this is meant to illustrate the concept, not be a cut 'n paste fix

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[])

app.service("logonService", function() {
    var loginURL = "http://testurl.com:4800/webapi/";
    var httpclient = new hprose.HttpClient(loginUrl, ["login"]);

    this.logon = function(userid, ppt) {
        // the result of httpclient.login is already a promise object.
        return httpclient.login(userid, ppt);
    }
})

app.controller（"myCtrl", ["logonService", 
    function(logonService) {
        logonService.logon(userid, ppt).then(function(user){
            //  assign user to scope only after promise resolved
            //  'user' arg will be whatever passed to 'resolve' above
            $scope.user = user; 
        })
        .catch(function(e){
            console.log('An Error happened: ' + e)
            // logon server was down, etc.
        })
    }
])
```

the result of httpclient.login is already a promise object, so you don't need use $q to wrap it.